# Parse query only returning the first and last queries

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am creating a query in Parse using multiple elements. The problem is that my query is only returning the first and last results and I'm not sure why. Any insight on this issue or on a better way to query multiple objects would be appreciated.

```
var GroupDetailObject = Parse.Object.extend("Group_Detail");
var query = new Parse.Query(GroupDetailObject);
var tempQuery = new Parse.Query(GroupDetailObject);

query.equalTo("groupId", {
    __type: "Pointer",
    className: "Groups",
    objectId: groups[0].objectId
});

for (ss = 1; ss < groups.length; ss++) {
    tempQuery.equalTo("groupId", {
        __type: "Pointer",
        className: "Groups",
        objectId: groups[ss].objectId
    });
    query = Parse.Query.or(query, tempQuery);
}

query.find({
```

Comment: It's quite possible `Parse.Query.or` just keeps a pointer to the `tempQuery` and uses its contents much later (when you actually send the query). In this case, `tempQuery` will contain the last condition you set (ORed together multiple times). You would then need to create a new `tempQuery` on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Thanks jcaron.  That is what was happening.  I moved `var tempQuery = new Parse.Query(GroupDetailObject);` inside of the for loop and the query completed successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var GroupDetailObject = Parse.Object.extend("Group_Detail");
var query = new Parse.Query(GroupDetailObject);

for (ss = 1; ss < groups.length; ss++) {
    var tempQuery = new Parse.Query(GroupDetailObject);
    tempQuery.equalTo("groupId", {
        __type: "Pointer",
        className: "Groups",
        objectId: groups[ss].objectId
    });
    query = Parse.Query.or(query, tempQuery);
}
```